# Is is possible to save client images on server using web services instead of WCF?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, silverlight-5.0

I am doing silver light application. 
Which I need to save `client Images` on `server folder`. For that purpose i am using `WCF Service`, and it works fine.

```
But what I required is instead of `WCF`. can use Web services ?.
```

if any one know please get me suggestions.
thanks advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send image as byte array through a web service function taking bytearray as parameter.

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/163276/upload-image-to-web-service-using-c

Comment: I did the same as in WCF. if you know any references please let me know.   @seyhan

Comment: i have add a link to my answer, I hope it helps.